Next config root html file name
In my next.js app (app router), I want to add a service worker. I want to add the root html file to the caches, but I'm not sure what it is called.
In development, it has its own custom name: my-app, without .html extention.
In production, it is called (index), without .html extention.
How do I know for sure how my root html file is called, and is there a possibility to actively rename it (ie to simply index.html)
